# Geometric series error/convergence counterexample (Strichartz)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm working through some problems in Strichartz's "The Way of Analysis", and there's one in chapter 7 that seems very unintuitive to me:

"Show that it is not true that for every error $1/m$ there exists $n$ such that $|\sum\limits_{k=1}^nr^k-\dfrac{r}{1-r}|<1/m$ for all $r$ in $0<r<1$."

My idea is to consider $r$ close to 1 and find a counterexample from there, but the whole premise of the problem seems counterintuitive since any geometric series with common ratio less than 1 converges. Could someone suggest an intuitive way to think about why the statement is not true?

For reference, so far I have that:

$|\sum\limits_{k=1}^nr^k-\dfrac{r}{1-r}|=|\dfrac{-r^n}{1-r}|=\dfrac{r^n}{1-r}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement (though rather obscured by the pile of quantifiers involved) is actually saying that there is no *uniform* bound on the difference between $r/(1-r)$ and its approximation by the first $n$ terms of the geometric series.

The reason this phenomenon occurs is essentially that $r/(1-r)$ is unbounded as $r$ approaches $1$, whereas each of the first $n$ terms of the series is always bounded above by $1$, so the sum of first $n$ of them is always smaller than $n$, so once $r/(1-r)$ goes above $n+1$, there's no way the difference can be made smaller than $1$, let alone $1/m$.

Comment: Ahh thank you! Can it sort of be thought of as a sort of analog to uniform continuity then?

Comment: It's a bit of a different beast: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence . It's about converging sequences of functions, rather than one function's variation.